# WTForms FormField causing csrf_token errors

Tags: python, flask, csrf, flask-wtforms

I have a flask project that basically has 2 Form Classes that act as a subform in the third Form Class. I use the 2 subforms with the FormField field. The problem is that when I submit the form, I get csrf_token errors for the two subforms. If I use the csrf=false property in the subforms I don't get this, but does this now mean I am open to CSRF attacks?

```
class AddressForm(FlaskForm):

    address = StringField(label='Address', validators=[DataRequired()])
    address2 = StringField(label='Address 2', validators=[Optional()])
    city = StringField(label='City', validators=[DataRequired()])
    county = SelectField(label='County', validators=[DataRequired()], choices=[], coerce=int)

    class Meta:
        csrf = False


class NameForm(FlaskForm):
    first_name = StringField(label='First Name', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2)] )
    last_name = StringField(label='Last Name', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2)] )

    class Meta:
        csrf = False

class OrderForm(FlaskForm):

    # Customer Details
    customer_name = FormField(NameForm, separator='_')
    customer_email = EmailField(label='Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    customer_mobile_phone = StringField(label='Mobile Phone Number', validators=[DataRequired()])
    customer_alternative_phone = StringField(label='Alternative Phone Number', validators=[Optional()])
    # Delivery Details
    delivery_address = FormField(AddressForm, separator='_')
    area = SelectField(label='Area', validators=[DataRequired()], coerce=int)
```

I have included the `{{ form.hidden_tag() }}` in the form and also have a SECRET_KEY configured.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after a lot of searching and watching videos, I noticed that everything referred to Form and not FlaskForm when doing FormFields. It seems like you can only have one FlaskForm on a page....the subforms must be Form class. I changed my subforms to inherit from Form instead of FlaskForm and it worked. FlaskForm inherits from Form and has csrf enabled and configured by default.

- https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/form.html
- https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#flask_wtf.FlaskForm
- https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/forms/

```
class AddressForm(Form):

    address = StringField(label='Address', validators=[DataRequired()])
    address2 = StringField(label='Address 2', validators=[Optional()])
    city = StringField(label='City', validators=[DataRequired()])
    county = SelectField(label='County', validators=[DataRequired()], choices=[], coerce=int)


class NameForm(Form):
    first_name = StringField(label='First Name', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2)] )
    last_name = StringField(label='Last Name', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2)] )
```

Comment: for investingating purposes, I would add that if you look at your form errors carefully you notice that the subforms have crsf_token missing, but not the parent form

Answer (score 0):

You include `{{ form.csrf_token }}` inside your form tag to use CSRF protection. [Per the documentation,](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/csrf.html)

> When using a FlaskForm, render the form's CSRF field like normal.
>
> ```
> <form method="post">
>     {{ form.csrf_token }}
> </form>
> ```
>
> If the template doesn't use a FlaskForm, render a hidden input with the token in the form.
>
> ```
> <form method="post">
>     <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
> </form>
> ```

You may find it helpful to refer to the general [Flask-WTF documentation](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/) on basic usage instructions.

Comment: I am using the form.hidden_tag() which also renders the csrf token:

https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#flask_wtf.FlaskForm.hidden_tag

Comment: @Lazypaddy I'm not seeing that in the docs you sent me, nor in trying it myself.

Comment: I'm not sure how to help here. It just works...if you use the form.hidden_tag() in your form instead of the form.csrf_token you will see that it inserts the csrf token as well as any other hidden tags. The CSRF token is a hidden tag.

Comment: From Miguel Grinberg:

The form.hidden_tag() template argument generates a hidden field that includes a token that is used to protect the form against CSRF attacks. All you need to do to have the form protected is include this hidden field and have the SECRET_KEY variable defined in the Flask configuration. If you take care of these two things, Flask-WTF does the rest for you.

[https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iii-web-forms](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iii-web-forms)